# apache qpid Request-Response

Tags: spring-integration, amqp, spring-amqp, qpid

I have not found any document or samples around implementing request-response using Apache qpid or even AMQP in general, is this supported and efficient solution?
Any relevant info would be greatly appreciated.

Since i am using spring and spring-integration so any built in support there would be great to know.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder which documentation have you read, but here is an info from [Spring AMQP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#request-reply) and from [Spring Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-outbound-gateway). And here is a [Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/applications/cafe/cafe-amqp/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/amqp/cafeDemo-amqp-operations-xml.xml).

I'm not familiar with qpid, but looks like it can work as is on the Spring RabbitMQ implementation. At least in the most cases.

Comment: Thanks Artem, i was looking in qpid docs and did not found anything helpful. This seems very helpful, just a followup question, how do random clients specify their response queue and how are those gets managed (created and destroyed) at broker level? I am looking at thousands of clients sending some requests and waiting for response.

Comment: It doesn't matter for Broker. Please, read more Spring AMQP Manual. `RabbitTemplate` takes about `anonymous auto-deleted` reply queues for each request. You can do that with `fixed` reply queue, of course. But in that case your received should take care about `correlationId` for the response.

Comment: Good "Thank you" is acceptance of an answer ;-). Glad to see, that I helped a bit!